# Unity WebGL rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, shadow, unity-webgl

When running WebGl app on PC browser, there is a rendering problem. Blurry image above the red line and also shadows disappearing above line[image]

Anybody knows what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved blurry image problem by increasing aniso level in texture import settings